# Python-docx cells returning tuple instead of list

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

Working in Python 3 with python-docx 0.8.6

I am trying to create a simple table by building it up one row at a time.  This generates an error:

> TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

```
    numCols = 2
    numRows = 0 #dynamically create table
    activeTable = document.add_table(rows=numRows, cols=numCols)
    for actorIndex in reversed(actorsRanked):
        cells = activeTable.add_row().cells
        cells[0] = '{:20}'.format(actorIndex.id.get())
        cells[1] = '{:4.1}'.format(actorIndex.pains[painIndex].avg)
```

Not only is this technique is based on the python-docx example provided on the quickstart page [here](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html), it's working elsewhere in my program.

Comment: You need to include the full stack trace. Otherwise we need to guess which line is triggering the error and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Row.cells` is a tuple. A tuple is immutable; you cannot assign to an element of it like you can a list.

In any case, I think what you want here is `cells[0].text = ...`, which is what is shown in the documentation you link to.